# Ajax все равно обновляет страницу. ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-core

Есть асинхронный запрос AJAX, который норм работает, данные в контроллер ходят без проблем и на контроллере тоже все норм работает. Контроллер обновляет данные пользователя. Но если это асинхронный запрос, то он не должен перезагружать страницу.  Вот скрипт который срабатывает при загрузке страницы, Достаем данные и распаршиваем в таблицу. Все ок тут.

```
function getDataList() {
var serviceURL = '/api/ProfessorsApi/';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: serviceURL,
    contentType: "application/json;",
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});
function successFunc(data, status) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Вот скрипт пост метода асинхронного аякс

```
function postData() {
let nameStudent = document.querySelector('[name="Name"]').value;

let surnameStudent = document.querySelector('[name="Surname"]').value;

let midlnameStudent = document.querySelector('[name="Midlname"]').value;

let emailStudent = document.querySelector('[name="Email"]').value;

let telephoneStudent = document.querySelector('[name="TelNumber"]').value;

let oldEmailStudent = document.querySelector('[name="OldEmail"]').value;

var parametrs = {
    Name: nameStudent, Surname: surnameStudent, Midlname: midlnameStudent,
    Email: emailStudent, TelNumber: telephoneStudent, OldEmail: oldEmailStudent
};
var serviceURL = '/api/ProfessorsApi/';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceURL,
    data: JSON.stringify(parametrs),
    contentType: "application/json;",
    //success: successFunc,
    //error: errorFunc
});
function successFunc(data, status) {

}

function errorFunc() {

}
```

И вот форма HTML  асинхронного запроса которая на onclick отправляет на функцию potsData(). Она в диалоговом окне открывается бутстрапа.

```
<div id="myModalBox" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Редагувати</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <label>Ім'я</label>
                        <input  name="Name" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Прізвище</label>
                        <input  name="Surname" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>По батькові</label>
                        <input  name="Midlname" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Email address</label>
                        <input  name="Email" type="email" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Tel Number</label>
                        <input  name="TelNumber" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input  name="OldEmail" type="password" class="form-control hidden" />
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Відмінити</button>
                    <input type="submit" onclick="postData()" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ну и на последок, контроллер

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> Post([FromBody]UpdateUserViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.OldEmail).Result;

            if (user != null)
            {
                user.Email = model.Email;
                user.Name = model.Name;
                user.Surname = model.Surname;
                user.Midlname = model.Midlname;

                var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var studentUpdate = _db.ProfessorModel.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Email == model.OldEmail);

                    if (studentUpdate != null)
                    {
                        studentUpdate.Name = model.Name;
                        studentUpdate.Surname = model.Surname;
                        studentUpdate.Midlname = model.Midlname;
                        studentUpdate.TelNumber = model.TelNumber;
                        studentUpdate.Email = model.Email;

                        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }

                    //await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                }
            }
        }

        return "Ok";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась тем что просто нужно в HTML форме поменять тег input  type="submit"  на  button. Оно ведь так и есть. Сабмит по идеи и должен перезагружать страницу. Поменял и все ок без перезагрузки все работает.

Comment: Можно оставить type="submit", просто по клику делать `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: либо просто 'return false' при выходе из обработчика jquery